# Having trouble restoring individual GarageBand projects from Time Machine

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine, backup, restore, garageband

I am trying to grab some old GarageBand project files from my live Time Machine backup that lives on an external drive that was formatted by Time Machine, and move them to my main desktop drive.
I can see three kinds of .band files in my Time Machine files, which I am guessing represent three different versions of GarageBand over the years.

I select a backup from fairly far back, like 2012, search for .band files in it, see a bunch of project files with different icons, ranging from the little guitar that GarageBand itself uses (I think these are the oldest projects), to a light gray rectangle (the medium-oldest), to a dark gray rectangle (the most recent projects).

I selected the group of files with the dark gray icons, clicked Restore, and got a message saying the enclosing folder was no longer there, to select another location.  I successfully deposted them in my Applications folder, and then moved them to a new folder I created on my desktop.

I returned to Time Machine to retrieve the other GarageBand project files, and now every time I select even one file of any type, even non-GarageBand files, I get the "volume has the wrong case sensitivy for a backup" error message when I click Restore.

Everything I have read about restoring selected files from Time Machine says that this should be simple operation with no problems as long as I select "another location" wherein to deposit my files.  I'm not trying to create a new volume, nor restore an entire Time Machine backup, just grab a few files like it describes on the tutorial for rescuing files one might have erroneously deleted.

On an Apple Community thread that someone else started that is now marked "complete", an Apple User named Comebackfreddy had a suggestion to someone asking this same question to put the selected files into the Trash and then open Trash and drag them to the target "another location" folder.  I would like to try that, but in Time Machine on Snow Leopard I do not know how to access the Trash folder from within Time Machine, nor how to put an individual data file into Trash.  Do you have a suggestion there?

I have rebooted my computer in case there was a messed-up pointer, nothing changed.  I am current through the 10.6.8 update to Snow Leopard, running on an iMac from 2008.